# What is the size of an integer in Eiffel? How does it handle overflow?

Tags: integer, integer-overflow, eiffel

In [Eiffel](http://eiffel.org), what is the size of an `INTEGER` type?

I was not able to find it, except [here](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~odunlain/eiffel/html/base/INTEGER.html), where it is claimed that the size is 32 bits.

In this case, how does Eiffel handle overflow? Is it undefined behavior like in C? Or is there a mechanism to prevent overflow?

If there is any resource where I can find it, then please direct me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [ECMA standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-367.htm) `INTEGER` is defined as an alias for one of the sized variants of integer classes with the recommended size of 64 bits. However, because there is a lot of existing code, current implementations still use 32-bit integers for `INTEGER`. The size can be set by a compiler option (e.g., [EiffelStudio](https://www.eiffel.org/) uses an Eiffel Configuration File (ECF) to map `INTEGER` to `INTEGER_32`, this is done in the core library `Base`). In principle, a library or an application can specify a different size for `INTEGER` type using type mapping. The mechanism is not part of Eiffel language specification, therefore usually sized variants are used directly when a specific size is required.

Eiffel standard does not define precise behavior of basic types, i.e. they are treated like any other types from the language perspective. All implementations, I know of, do not check for integer overflow or underflow and silently wrap the result modulo their size.

There are several library-based solutions that provide arbitrary precision integer arithmetic:

- [factorial](http://efsa.sourceforge.net/archive/waquier/factoria.htm) (1994, tested with TowerEiffel 1.3.1)  - `FACTORIAL` represents big integer values
- [big_numbers](http://efsa.sourceforge.net/archive/hillion/big_numbers.htm) (1998, tested with SmallEiffel -0.80) - `BIG_INTEGER` with a set of other numeric classes
- eapml (Eiffel Arbitrary Precision Mathematics Library) (contemporary, included in standard EiffelStudio distribution under *contrib*) - `INTEGER_X` - an arbitrary precision integer
- dcm (contemporary, included in standard EiffelStudio distribution under *contrib*) and gobo (contemporary, part of Gobo framework, included in standard EiffelStudio distribution under *contrib*) - `DECIMAL` and `MA_DECIMAL` respectively - decimal numbers following the [General Decimal Arithmetic Specification](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/)

Comment: Thank you. So does it mean that overflow is undefined behavior?

Comment: @GoodDeeds, Overflow is neither detected nor reported by the standard integer classes.

Comment: So in that case, is the resultant value of the `INTEGER` object defined to be modulo of the overflowed value with the size of is it undefined?

Comment: @GoodDeeds, The resulting value is the overflowed value modulo integer size.